# SwiftUI run function every time app is opened

Tags: swiftui, initialization

I have a very troubling problem. I have searched for days on how to solve it. I have some code that I want to run every time the app is opened, **not just when the app is launched for the first time**. I've basically tried everything available. I've tried `scenePhase`, I've tried `AppDelegate`, I've tried `onAppear`, I've tried `init` and custom extensions to the `View` class, I've even tried simply running a function in the view, but nothing is working. I'll show my code here.

```swift
@main
struct CouponDeckApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            AppContentView()
                
        }
    }
}

struct AppContentView: View {
    init() {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        
        if userDefaults.value(forKey: "hour") == nil { // 1
            userDefaults.set(9, forKey: "hour") // 2
        }
        
        // 3
        if userDefaults.value(forKey: "minute") == nil {
            userDefaults.set(30, forKey: "minute")
        }
    }
    @State var currentview: String = "Main"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Group {
            switch currentview {
            case "Main":
                MainView(currentview: $currentview)
                    
            case "Form":
                FormView(currentview: $currentview)
            case "Settings":
                SettingsView(currentview: $currentview)
            default:
                if currentview.contains("Coupon") {
                    CouponView(currentview: $currentview)
                }
                else {
                    EditView(currentview: $currentview)
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}

//MainView(), CouponView(), FormView(), etc.
```

I'm starting to suspect that the problem is with the `switch` statement in `AppContentView` that allows you to move between the different views.

Does anyone know:
A. Why this is happening,
B. How to fix it, or
C. Another alternative?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm running my code on the simulator.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a very simple way, using native scenePhase, I did not make it more complicated. You can use Preference method as well for better result! But onChange is good enough for this example:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Welcome to my App!")
            .onAppear() { customFunction() }
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
                
                if newPhase == .active {
                    customFunction()
                }
                
            }
        
    }
}


func customFunction() {
    print("App is opened!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it in your `AppDelegate`'s [`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application).

Comment: OP said "every time the app is opened, not when the app is launched for the first time" though

Comment: I assumed "app is launched for the first time" means first launch after installation. Detecting first launch after install using `UserDefaults` is something well covered by other pages on stackoverflow.

Comment: Ah. I thought they were counting an "open" as pressing home button to go to home screen, then clicking on app.

Comment: @aheze: OP: "I have some code that I want to run every time the app is opened, not just when the app is launched for the first time."

Answer (score 1):

The simple problem was that it doesn't work when you close out of the app. I realized if you just exit the app but don't completely close out of it, it works just fine.

I also learned about the `NotificationCenter`'s applications to this. By triggering a response when `UIApplication` sends out the `willEnterForegroundNotification` by using the `onReceive` method, you can trigger a response that way.